# EAC Admin Console is not opening up?

Tags: atg, endeca, oracle-commerce, endeca-workbench

When I try to hit my site, I am getting the following error:

> Error Tue May 10 16:54:40 IST 2016 1462879480679
>   /atg/endeca/assembler/droplet/InvokeAssembler A problem occurred
>   assembling the content for content item /content/Web/Home Pages. The
>   response received was {previewModuleUrl=http://localhost:8006/ifcr,
>   @type=ContentSlot, atg:currentSiteProductionURL=www.local.com:7103,
>   canonicalLink=com.endeca.infront.cartridge.model.NavigationAction@49dded95,
>   ruleLimit=1, @error=com.endeca.infront.content.ContentException:
>   com.endeca.navigation.ENEConnectionException: Error establishing
>   connection to retrieve Navigation Engine request
>   'http://localhost:15000/graph?node=0&profiles=NoPriceRange|site&offset=0&nbins=0&merchdebug=1&irversion=640'.
>   Tried all: '2' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server:
>   'localhost', port: '15000' Check MDEX Logs and specified query
>   parameters. , contentCollection=/content/Web/Home Pages}. Servicing
>   the error open parameter.

When I try to access EAC Admin Console to restart MDEX Engine, it is not getting loaded.  Why that might be?

---

Comment: Are all your Endeca services started?

Comment: What's the output when you hit that URL appending "&format=xml" to it? http://localhost:15000/graph?node=0&profiles=NoPriceRange|site&offset=0&nbins=0&merchdebug=1&irversion=640&format=xml

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your endeca servers are running. Try to access localhost:8500/cas?wsdl
Is the Dgraph port provided as 15000 in all configurations?